# How many possible arrangements are there for the pile of cards where the first 3 cards are face cards and the last 2 cards are even numbered cards?

Tags: combinatorics

A 52 card deck of common playing cards is well shuffled to ensure the cards are in random order.

How many possible arrangements are there for the pile of cards where the first 3 cards are face cards (Jack, Queen, or King) and the last 2 cards are even numbered cards?

I'm not sure how to arrive at the answer which equals (320)(380)(47!) ≈ 1.2973 × 10^65 according to answer key.

Comment: you could try combinatorics

Comment: You have a typographical error in the answer.  The first term should be $1320$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $12$ face cards, and $12\cdot11\cdot 10$ ways to arrange three of them. There are $20$ even cards, and $20\cdot 19$ ways to arrange two of them. There are $47!$ ways to arrange the remaining $47$ cards. This gives $1320\cdot 380\cdot 47!$ ways.

Comment: So the Jack, queen and King don't represent 11, 12, and 13 respectively and Queen isn't an "even" card?

Comment: No they are separate. In games, face cards are sometimes all worth $10$, but in this context they are just face cards.